# Why does Substrate use both Rust's Logging API crate and frame_support::log?

Tags: debugging, logging, frame-support

In the Substrate documentation here https://docs.substrate.io/test/debug/ it says we can use [Rust's Logging API crate](https://crates.io/crates/log), for example as follows in a pallet:

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
frame-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", "branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.36" }
log = "0.4.17"
```

lib.rs

```
use log::{debug, error, info, trace, warn};
...
info!("logging");
```

However, the Substrate documentation does not mention we may alternatively use frame_support::log instead, for example as follows in a pallet:

```
use frame_support::log::{debug, error, info, trace, warn};
...
info!("logging");
```

Substrate uses Rust's Logging API crate almost everywhere throughout the codebase, but only uses `frame_support::log` in a few places like Frame Executive, for example [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/executive/src/lib.rs#L242)

Why doesn't Substrate only use Rust's Logging API crate?
Why does it also need and use frame_support::log?
Should Substrate developers only use Rust's Logging API crate or frame_support::log or their choice of either of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because different contributor has different knowledge of Substrate or Rust.

I use `frame_support::log` everywhere in my project. Because I know there is a `pub use` in the frame-support, and I also don't want to modify my toml file.

---

It is just like someone importing `DispatchResult` from the frame-support and someone importing it from the sp-runtime.